# get_assignments of training data with StreamMOA package

Tags: r, stream, cluster-analysis

I am using StreamMOA package in R for stream clustering and trying to make comparison between all available stream clustering algorithms.
There is any way to get assignments of trained data after executing update()? I don't think using get_assignment() with the same data is the proper way to do it because those point already clustered.
get_clustering_assignment() method does not work for all algorithms

Comment: Get the source code of MOA, and use it without R wrapping, but natively.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this package is wrapped.